# How do I get .doc format files that contain pictures to load in an NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, osx-lion

I'm working on an OSX 10.7 xcode project and have looked around the web but can't seem to find a way to get my .doc format files to load into an NSTextView properly. The rich text gets displayed but the pictures aren't displayed.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
documentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[openDocumentPanel URL] relativePath]];
[[_documentView textStorage] setAttributedString: [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithDocFormat:documentData documentAttributes:nil]];
```